# How to Display two TextBox values in one TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

[image]

How to show two textbox values in one textbox

I don't want to add or multiply only display the Value that I entered in the textbox

Comment: what have you tried so far - please do not expect us to do your coding for you from scratch

Comment: is this a windows app, or web app?

Comment: Normally we would need to know which GUI. But across the various C# UI libraries: `textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text  + "+" + textBox2.Text;` ought to work.

Comment: `textBox3.Text = $"{textBox1.Text}+{textBox2.Text}";`

Comment: thankuu sir its working!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
TextBox3.Text = TextBox1.Text + "+" + Textbox2.Text;
```

Comment: thanks its working fine!   How to write in Visual Basic

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)